# How to disable Dyntopo by default?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

One quick question: How can I set the dyntopo option to be DISABLED by default when switching to sculpt mode? 
The background for this is, that I don't want my mesh to get triangulated as soon as I switch to sculpt mode, since I only want to fine tune my mesh with the grab brush etc.
I am using blender 2.81 (release version) at the moment, but have seen the same behavior in the release version of 2.80.
Thanks in advance for any help in this matter!

Answer (score 0):

I already found he answer myself: It turned out that the version of the Heavypoly UI Config that I used had the dyntopo parameter integrated by default into the script that facilitates the switch into sculpt mode from a pie menu ;)